# Typescript Array[T] accepts {..T} as valid type

Tags: typescript, types

This bit me when using `useState<Options[]>` as a react hook, when I mistyped `{...options}` instead of `[...options]`, I only found out when I tried to access `.map` of "array" (object) and got a TypeError. Let me give you an example that can clarify my question:

```
  interface Option {
    title: string;
    isSelected?: boolean;
  }

  function myFunc(options: Option[]): void {}

  const options: Option[] = [{title: 'Male', isSelected: true}, {title: 'Female'}, {title: 'Other'}];
  const options2 = {...options};
  myFunc(options);
  myFunc(options2); // why isn't this an error ?
```

Comment: is short: typeof array is object, so typescript doesn't care, meaning array can be converto to object, and vice versa

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly surely TS already differentiates between `T[]` and `T`, so it's not as simple as "arrays are objects" since if this were true `T[] = T` if `T` is an object. From *this example*, it seems to treat an array-like an array as the same but there might be an option to restrict that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be indeed a problem with Typescript itself:

```
let c: number[] = { ...[0, 1, 2] }; // compiles
c.fill(0) // runtime error

let d: number[] = Object.assign({}, [0, 1, 2]);  // compiles
d.fill(0) // runtime error
```

Moreover, this also compiles and breaks at run-time:

```
class E {
    method() { }
}

let e: E = Object.assign({}, new E)
e.method() // runtime error
```

[PG](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/DYUwLgBAhgXBB2BXAtgIxAJwNoF0IF4IBvCUeAczAAs4BmAGggCIAGJuFxpgRnYm64AmPoIgBfANwQIAehkQA9gGtGAEwUgAzvADkkAMYLkABwCWoAFAXQkVHCRpMuAhADyqAFYh9YAHRRNTVNyeAAKIjFGEjJKGggGZjYOLl44AWZhOFExAEopOUUVCHUtXQMjM0trcAh9exR0bDxCEl82rE5+RkE8SVl5QxNzLQt9XwAzc2BQlhz+iAxEeDBTZBAITAwFDCsbYvrHJpd3Lx9-QOCwiMYOxnSevOkCwcqR1QmpmbmCxeXV9c22ys+mAAU0EAAosQLNJpGtqApVKE5iQxBY0dVICA4FDCCdvH4wZdwpEECAAO6QnIWEC+eFURHI+a-FZrDYYLY7CxAA)

I guess this is because `Object.assign` is declared as

```
assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U;
```

which is incorrect, since what `assign` returns doesn't actually extend `U`. The return type of `assign` should be something like `T & OwnProperties<U>`, but this is currently not possible, see

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28801
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9726

Comment: TypeScript's type system has no way to represent own or enumerable properties in general, so its object spread behavior is not safe.  There was a [proposal](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727) to try to represent object spread at the type level and this problem was mentioned (see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727#issuecomment-245044382) and subsequent comments).  There's just no great answer to this right now, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Playing around on the [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=11&ssc=49&pln=9&pc=15#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYmQbwChkTkswAbCALmQGcwpQBzAbmNODoGUIqFIAEwD8tAEbZsVOCHYkAvoQ4wAriAE48AWwCeAMTUIAFNkya6tDFlwBtALoBKWgDdswQQUUcEuBslPWIBZoZrZ2yAC8yDb45FS0AOQAsnBUCQA0yFy8-EK0jCoQ8pmxwJQ0yAl6EFqpEAnFBHEVCahgABbQDXZyyD5BYP6hQQBMkQQAdFMB5vK9ugbqJsN0DvP6hsuBdCNryAD0+8gA7u06WXQgCYMdXMgyyNBQ2FDIwkA), it seems typescript thinks `options2` is defined as:

```
const options2: {
    [x: number]: Option;
    length: number;
    toString(): string;
    toLocaleString(): string;
    pop(): Option | undefined;
    push(...items: Option[]): number;
    concat(...items: ConcatArray<Option>[]): Option[];
    concat(...items: (Option | ConcatArray<...>)[]): Option[];
    ... 24 more ...;
    [Symbol.unscopables](): {
        ...;
    };
}
```

So, it actually looks like an array of type Option `Option[]`. But the spread operator doesn't actually copy the Array prototype members and the new object is definitely not an array. I would say this is a bug in the typescript type system.

Comment: They would probably say it's a design limitation as opposed to a bug.  [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/28234) is the relevant object spread pull request, and it admits that [own/enumerable properties can't be tracked](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/28234#issuecomment-434444188).