# Pick "own" properties from a type

Tags: typescript

I'd like to construct a type that contains only "own" properties of another type.

```
interface A {
  a: number;
}

interface B extends A {
  b: number;
}

interface C extends B {
  c: number;
}

type OwnProperties<T> = ??? 

let x : OwnProperties<C> // `{c:number}`
```

How can I write `OwnProperties` using the derived type only, without passing supertypes explicitly?

See [Typescript Array[T] accepts {..T} as valid type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58374699/typescript-arrayt-accepts-t-as-valid-type/) for the motivational example.

Comment: If two types are structurally equivalent, then you can't expect the compiler to treat them differently (the compiler *might* treat them differently, but the rule of thumb is that the type system is structural and two types which are structurally identical are actually the same type).  Since `interface CPrime {a: number; b: number; c: number}` is structurally identical to `C`, and since you'd presumably want `OwnProperties<CPrime>` to be different from `OwnProperties<C>`, it's a hint that `OwnProperties<>` either can't be written or can't be relied upon if you can.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript: Get Type of Super Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56377792/typescript-get-type-of-super-class), not that there's any answers there either

Comment: @jcalz: thanks. How would you type `Object.assign` properly then? (see the linked question)

Comment: I think right now the answer is [you can't](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9726).

Comment: @jcalz: `Object.assign` and object spreads being inherently broken - an edge case? OK...